# If $a, b, c,$ and $d$ are integers and $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}$ where both sides of the equation be the same

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

If  we have  integers $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}$,when will both sides of the equation be the equal.

So what that means is that for integers $a, b, c,$ and $d$ will it be possible to come up with $c$ and $d$ so that they are not the same as $a$ and $b$. Can somebody please tell me if this is possible and also give me an example if it is.

Comment: Some advice - If you are going to ask questions here, you might want to learn up how to type math formulae in MathJax. Here's a good tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For instance, $$\frac13+\frac13=\frac12+\frac16$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}{1\over16}+{1\over48}&={1\over21}+{1\over28}={1\over18}+{1\over36}=\\{1\over20}+{1\over30}&={1\over15}+{1\over60}={1\over14}+{1\over84}\end{align}$$

I wonder if there are arbitrarily large sets like this.  I would guess yes.

In Theorem 2 of [this paper](http://www.nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-19/NNTDM-19-2-15-25.pdf) it is shown that the number of solutions in positive integers $x,y$ to $${1\over x}+{1\over y}={1\over n}$$ is $\tau(n^2)$, where $\tau(n)$ is the number of positive divisors of $n$ so that there are indeed arbitrarily large sets of two-term Egyptian fractions with the same sum.

Comment: If $(a,b,c,d)$ is one such $4$-tuple, then certainly $(ma,mb,mc,md)$ is another.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Yes, but they don't have the same sum.

Comment: Ah, ok. Arbitrarily large meant arbitrarily large sets ot pairs with fixed harmonic sum.