Can any rational between 0 and 1 be the sum of two unique natural reciprocals?
I currently have a type of set I'm working with, namely
$$S_j = \{1/j + 1/n : n \in \mathbb N_{> j}\}$$
For example, $S_2 = \{1/2 + 1/3, 1/2 + 1/4, \ldots\}$. I want to answer the question whether or not $S_i$ and $S_j$ are disjoint for any $i \neq j$. The only thing I've achieved so far is showing that $(n + j)im = (i + m)nj$, where $n > j$ and $m > i$, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

I don't understand the question.  How is, say, $3$, the sum of "two unique reciprocals"?

@lulu I wasn't sure how to phrase this exactly; perhaps it might be better for me to write the title as: "Are $S_i$ and $S_j$ disjoint?"

I don't understand.  $\frac 14+\frac 14=\frac 13+\frac 16$.  Is that the sort of thing you are asking about?

@lulu Yes, but $\frac14 + \frac14$ wouldn't be allowed in this case; I'd only allow fractions whose denominators are greater than 4 to be added.

$1/5+1/20=1/6+1/12$

@Eric Is there any way to procedurally generate these pairs?

More (counter)examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3231692/42969

Sums of distinct reciprocals of positive integers are called Egyptian fractions. They have been much studied since ancient times.  See the Wikipedia link for more information.

You never mentioned the condition on the denominator, but of course it doesn't change anything (just divide every fraction in my example by some large integer).

@randommathacc You may wish to ask a new question about procedural generation of such fractions (as you asked of Eric in the comments). That question does not seem to be addressed in the linked post.
